# Security header is not valid - WP E-commerce

Tags: wordpress, security, paypal, e-commerce

I am using WP E-Commerce (Version 3.8.14.1) and WordPress (WordPress 3.9.1) for the following site:

https://www.westernblotservice.com/

Payments are set up though PayPal Payments Standard 2.0 and PayPal Pro 2.0. Standard works flawlessly, but there is a problem with PayPal Pro. After the item is added to the cart and credit card information is inserted, I get the following error "Security header is not valid".

I triple checked all the information (API username, password, signature), made sure there aren't extra characters, deleted and issued new API username, password, signature, nothing seems to help. Sandbox mode isn't checked in WP E-Commerce. I am pretty sure I am using Live API information from my PayPal account (from Profile/Selling tools). I called PayPal and verified that everything is set up correctly. They told me it's an error on the plug-in's side.

I created a test product for $0.01, it can be added to the cart here:

https://www.westernblotservice.com/test-2/

Clicking Order Now should take you to the shopping cart page where the erorr occurs.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This error indicates in almost all cases that your API credentials are invalid. Double check them and if you are convinced they are correct, check your endpoint. Live credentials will not work in the test environment and sandbox credentials will not work in Live.

Comment: Triple checked APIs, issued new ones and tried them. Even switched the plug-in to the Sandbox mode - still didn't work. I'm not sure what you mean by "check your end point". I'm a newbie, sorry :)

Comment: I just tried deleting and re-issuing API credentials and it worked! Have done it before and it didn't help. Thanks for your help! Glad it got resolved!